# Translation of "time-sensitive"

Tags: traducción

I have this sentence:

> Because this matter is time-sensitive, I need to be sure you will be available if needed.

And I translated it as follows:

> Debido a que este asunto es ????, quiero asegurarme de que usted estará disponible si lo es necesario.

What is the idiomatic equivalent (castellano) for "time sensitive"?

*(other corrections and idiomatic adjustments welcome too, of course)*

Comment: Forgot to specify region (Spain/castellano). I edited that into my post.

Comment: I know it's not an accurate translation, but you can use the adjectives that mean "urgent", as _apremiante, urgente, imperioso_ o _crítico_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some words you could use to convey the urgency of something that is time-sensitive, although there seems not to be a direct translation for the term in Spanish.

For example

> Debido a que este asunto es **apremiante**

In Spanish ["Apremiar"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=L2rUizLDbDXX2uhazvib) means

> Dar prisa, compeler a alguien a que haga prontamente algo

You could also use "impostergable". ["Postergar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TpOwjdv) is a synonym of "procrastinate". Thus, "impostergable" means that this business can't go beyond a certain deadline. Idem for ["Aplazar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3CSmSyz|3CTBIvJ)

> Debido a que este asunto es **impostergable**
>
> Debido a que este asunto es **inaplazable**

You could also use a rather obscure word ["perentorio"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sa00Myd) which means "Urgente, apremiante."

> Debido a que este asunto es **perentorio**

But I think you would be better off using `apremiante`, `inaplazable` or `impostergable`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming "time-sensitive" means that the time is a key aspect in the topic, I would translate it to: **el tiempo es clave**.

> Debido a que en este asunto **el tiempo es clave**, quiero asegurarme de
>   que usted estará disponible si es necesario.

Note we say "si es necesario" and not "si *lo* es necesario".

Comment: Nice answer, @fedorqui

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. You could say:

> "Debido a que este asunto es referente a un *horario específico*,
>   necesito estar seguro de que estará disponible si es preciso".

In other sentences you could also use "horas concretas" or "estricto calendario", or "horario forzoso" or "horario inflexible".

> "Debido a que este asunto tiene un calendario estricto, ..."

Comment: I like these options. I think _calendario estricto_ captures the essence best. However, I forgot to mention in my original post that the context is _castellano_ and not Latin American.  Does that change your suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Yo usaría esto:

> Quiero asegurarme de que usted estará disponible si es necesario puesto que este asunto requiere acción **inmediata**.

Comment: Tengo curiosidad: ¿por qué se ha editado mi respuesta? ¡Gracias!